# Adding alarms to a calendar entry using AppleScript in Mavericks causes error

Tags: macos, applescript, calendar

I have following scripts (see bottom) that is meant to open all calendar entries and create alarms for each. **This is working fine on 10.8.x**. I've been testing the same script on Mavericks and I'm getting this error.

[image]

The error happens on the line that says "make new open file alarm...". If I commented these 2 lines, it proceeds fine.

Any ideas what could be wrong? I looking at the Applescript reference guide available online but I can't find the section that talks about make and it's a bit hard to search the net for the word "make" since it's pretty generic.

**Here's my code:**

```
set startFile to "/Users/" & UName & "/Desktop/my-app1-here.app"
set endFile to "/users/" & UName & "/Desktop/my-app2-here.app"

    tell application "Calendar"
        tell calendar "Home"
            delay 1
            set allEvents to every event

            repeat with rEvent in allEvents
                tell rEvent
                            set theDate to start date - 1 * minutes
                    set endDate to end date

                    if (minutes of (endDate) is 0) then
                        set endDate to endDate - 5 * minutes
                    end if

                    make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger date:theDate, filepath:startFile}
                    make new open file alarm at end with properties {trigger date:endDate, filepath:endFile}

                end tell
            end repeat

        end tell
```

**here's the console error message:**

```
7/05/2014 10:19:52.698 am Calendar[646]: [com.apple.calendar.ui.log] [Save failed with error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=1560 "Multiple validation errors occurred." UserInfo=0x608000866600 {NSDetailedErrors=(
    "Error Domain=CalCalendarStorePersistenceErrorDomain Code=1550 \"Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.\" UserInfo={\n    CalAlarmUID = \"2B8B98F1-0E23-45A7-AFDA-5AB692A36647\";\n    CalCalendarItemUID = \"79E93DF6-2073-40DF-BAB1-1642493B5B18\";\n    CalCalendarUID = \"DD5D4A36-F3E9-4BA7-A15B-A843D9381564\";\n    CalManagedObjectType = CalManagedAlarm;\n    NSLocalizedDescription = \"Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.\";\n}",
    "Error Domain=CalCalendarStorePersistenceErrorDomain Code=1550 \"Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.\" UserInfo={\n    CalAlarmUID = \"7729163B-0C99-4F21-AA2D-4A96E41D5045\";\n    CalCalendarItemUID = \"79E93DF6-2073-40DF-BAB1-1642493B5B18\";\n    CalCalendarUID = \"DD5D4A36-F3E9-4BA7-A15B-A843D9381564\";\n    CalManagedObjectType = CalManagedAlarm;\n    NSLocalizedDescription = \"Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.\";\n}"
)}]
7/05/2014 10:19:52.699 am Calendar[646]: Detailed error: Error Domain=CalCalendarStorePersistenceErrorDomain Code=1550 "Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path." UserInfo={
    CalAlarmUID = "2B8B98F1-0E23-45A7-AFDA-5AB692A36647";
    CalCalendarItemUID = "79E93DF6-2073-40DF-BAB1-1642493B5B18";
    CalCalendarUID = "DD5D4A36-F3E9-4BA7-A15B-A843D9381564";
    CalManagedObjectType = CalManagedAlarm;
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.";
}
7/05/2014 10:19:52.699 am Calendar[646]: Detailed error: Error Domain=CalCalendarStorePersistenceErrorDomain Code=1550 "Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path." UserInfo={
    CalAlarmUID = "7729163B-0C99-4F21-AA2D-4A96E41D5045";
    CalCalendarItemUID = "79E93DF6-2073-40DF-BAB1-1642493B5B18";
    CalCalendarUID = "DD5D4A36-F3E9-4BA7-A15B-A843D9381564";
    CalManagedObjectType = CalManagedAlarm;
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Alerts that open files or scripts must include a file path.";
}
```

Comment: Per the error message, what's it say in the console?

Comment: who does the "make new file" ?

Comment: I edited my post to show the console message. thanks again